# At what height would a pilot apply TOGA during a go around Vs getting simply vectored somewhere else?

Tags: airline-operations

If a pilot has to go around Early in a approach, he can simply be vectored to get reestablish. At what point would the pilot decide to apply TOGA other than obviously at minimums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime I want to execute the missed approach I would push the TOGA button anywhere after crossing the final approach fix.  I don't know what specific airplane you fly but the ones I do pushing the TOGA button does these things:

- Disconnect autopilot
- Sets flight director to 9° nose high in a wings level condition
- Sequences the FMS (FMC) to fly the missed approach

Comment: That's how the CRJs work, which have the Collins Pro Line Flight Director.

Answer (score 1):

When operating into airports with parallel runways airliners are sometimes given a runway change after being established on one ILS.

The procedure to follow is an “ILS Breakout”. eg (B767) If done with the autopilot engaged this requires a go-around to be commenced, initially TOGA, followed by a sequence of selections to hold the current altitude and control the airspeed before other selections to recommence a descent and to intercept the ILS for the new runway.

In the B767 the autopilot stays on when TOGA is selected.

A very busy procedure that should not be attempted in IMC below 1500 ft. ie Go-around and follow the missed approach procedure for the current runway.